# Java/Selenium: Still getting "ChromeDriver was started successfully" message after disabling logging

Tags: java, selenium, logging, console

I'm using the Selenium Chromedriver with Java. I don't want it to output any logs/messages in the console. Therefore I used the following code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");
    System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_SILENT_OUTPUT_PROPERTY, "true");
    Logger.getLogger("org.openqa.selenium").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

However, I'm still getting a single message: "ChromeDriver was started successfully". How can I prevent this message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redirect the output to a file or just discard it:

```
            // redirect console output from chromedriver to the file chromedriver_log.txt in the target folder
            DriverService.Builder<ChromeDriverService, ChromeDriverService.Builder> serviceBuilder = new ChromeDriverService.Builder();
            ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = serviceBuilder.build();
            chromeDriverService.sendOutputTo(new FileOutputStream("target/chromedriver_log.txt", true));

            webDriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
```

If you want to just discard the output then use `NullOutputStream.NULL_OUTPUT_STREAM` insted off `new FileOutputStream("target/chromedriver_log.txt", true)`

Comment: Works like a charm!


                `ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().build();
                chromeDriverService.sendOutputTo(NullOutputStream.NULL_OUTPUT_STREAM);
                WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);`

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the "ChromeDriver was started successfully" message comes from [this line](https://github.com/bayandin/chromedriver/blob/f456d840ef049a2ba73d60df67b85052822f99d9/server/chromedriver_server.cc#L239) at the ChromeDriver binary:

```
printf("%s was started successfully.\n", kChromeDriverProductShortName);
```

Maybe this `printf` statement that ends in the standard output, can be redirected somehow.

Comment: is there a solution for this?